# jQuery - Close dialog when click is made outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Every-time a user clicks on Register or Login link, a popup window appears to proceed. But the user is supposed to click Login or register link again if he wants to close the popup window. Is it possible to close the popup window if click is made outside on the webpage?

Here is the webpage link to see the live code if that helps: http://bit.ly/1oagBgx

This is the code for Dropdown menu on my webpage:

```
<!---dropdown--->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function showlogin(){
        $("#loginbox").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 800 });
        $("#regsiterbox").hide();
        $(".login a").css("color", "#bf1e1a");
        $(".create-account a").css("color", "#747474");
    }
    function showregister(){
        $("#regsiterbox").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 800 });
        $("#loginbox").hide();
        $(".create-account a").css("color", "#bf1e1a");
        $(".login a").css("color", "#747474");
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<!---dropdown--->
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: NB: mouse clicks are not the only way that users can "leave" a dialog. They might use the tab key, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.target.id as in Maulik's answer, but it might not work when you click on an element of your popup box, which cannot be delegated to the container.

You basically need two things:

1. Track the mouse hovering **in** and **out** on your popup dialog.
2. Bind an event handler for document's mouse up event, and check if the cursor is outside the popup. If the cursor is outside the popup, close it.

**Tracking mouse hover:** Note that the selector is [id$='box'] , so it matches all IDs that ends with 'box'. Make sure you change this as it fits for your app.

```
var insideMenu = false;
$("[id$='box']").hover(
    function(){
        insideMenu  = true;
    },
    function(){
        insideMenu  = false;
    }
);
```

**Binding document's mouse-up event**:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(){
     if(!insideMenu){
        $("#loginbox").hide();
      }
});
```

Comment: Posted an edit suggestion for this great answer. Change `#loginbox` to `[id$='box']`

Comment: Cool. Make sure to catch the second `#loginbox`

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple Code

```
var clickNo = 2;
    function yourFunction()
        {
        switch (clickNo) 
            {
            case 1:
                // Function : This will be onClick
                // For ex : document.getElementById('id').className = "hiddenClass";
                clickNo = 2
                    return(false);
            case 2:
                // Function : This will be byDefault
                // For ex : document.getElementById('id').className = "visibleClass";
                clickNo = 1
                    return(false);
            }
        }
```

In the Second case define the class name in which it is visible

and in the First define the class name in which it is hidden

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I just made example for login dialog box you can do same for register dialog

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if( e.target.id != 'loginbox') {
    $("#loginbox").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: you need to check whether `loginbox` is not an ancestor of the clicked element either.